# datetime.datetime conversion to datetime

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, datetime, casting

I have defined a column in `SQL Server` as `ldate` with `datetime` data type and accepting `null` values. I'm trying to send data from my local machine using python and `pyodbc`. I have date like `20-01-2015` in `string` format. When I try to send data it throws an error:

> pyodbc.DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')

So I convert that `string` to `datetime` format using

`datetime.datetime.strptime('20-01-2015', '%Y-%m-%d')`

This is `datetime.datetime` type. When I insert this value its throw below error

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot find either column "datetime" or the user-defined function or aggregate "datetime.datetime", or the name is ambiguous. (4121) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

I'm struck - any help?

Comment: Show us your code and the full error traceback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the time in your datetime string. You are just inserting date which is throwing first error.
You can solve this error by passing time with date string, see below example:

```
2015-01-20 00:00:00
```

Or you can use datetime module as below:

First make datetime object from the string:

```
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime('20-01-2015', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Then while inserting this datetime object into database convert it into the datetime string by simply `str` function

```
datetime_str = str(datetime_obj)
```

Now use this `datetime_str`.